# Verify Stokes Theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

---

Verify Stokes' Therorem when the vector field is

$F(x, y, z)$ = $yi - xj + yxk$, where $k$ is constant.

and $S$ is the paraboloid $z = x^{2} + y^2$ with the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, $z = 1$ as its boundary. Let $S$ be oriented with the outward normal.

---

I get $2\pi$ when I evaluate the flux of the curl side, but when I try to find the work around the curve, I get $-2\pi$. I'm not sure when I'm going wrong.

**UPDATE**

Turns out I Integrated my $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ terms instead of differentiating them.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I did it correctly. The answer is 2pi. Here is my working and how I got to -2pi. 

http://imgur.com/ANaA3ZI

Comment: When you differentiate $\cos t$ you should get $-\sin t$.

Comment: I'm not sure If I parametrize the Circle Curve properly. I'm always confused when it's clockwise and whether i put a negative in front of the x(t) or y(t) and what happens to the terminals :/

Comment: Wow -_-! Failed hard there. Thanks guys haha

@amzoti, Can you give me a run down on what to do when the parametrizing a circle? I don't actually understand it when its travelling clockwise. I've just been told to add a negative to x(t)? and even then, I'm not sure what I'm meant to do with the terminals. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa05/Parveen/Assignment%2010/parametric_equations.htm

Comment: @amzoti, Yes, I'll go though that now! Thanks!

Comment: @amzoti, I went through it and now I understand the  reason we have a negative out front when going from AntiCW to CW. $cos(t)$ ACW -> $cos(-t) = cos(t)$. Then $sin(t)$ ACW -> $sin(-t)$ CW = $-sin(t)$  

However, When you're in the CW, where does the angle $t=0$ start from? if I had a quarter of the unit circle going CW in quadrant 3, $(0,-1)$ to $(-1,0)$. What would my __ <= $t$ <= __ be??

Would it be $-π/2 <= t <= -π$

Comment: @amzoti, Yes! So the angle always starts on the positive x axis. Good! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\oint\vec{F}\cdot{\rm d}\vec{r}
&=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left\lbrace\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
\sin\left(\theta\right)
\left\lbrack -\sin\left(\theta\right){\rm d}\theta\vphantom{\Large A}\right\rbrack
+
\left\lbrack\vphantom{\Large A}-\cos\left(\theta\right)\right\rbrack
\left\lbrack\cos\left(\theta\right){\rm d}\theta\right\rbrack
\right\rbrace
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large-2\pi}
\end{align}

$$
\left(\nabla\times\vec{F}\right)_{z}
=
{\partial F_{y} \over \partial x} - { \partial F_{x} \over \partial y}
=
{\partial\left(-x\right) \over \partial x} - { \partial y \over \partial y}
=
-2
$$

$$
\int_{S}\nabla\times\vec{F}\cdot{\rm d}\vec{S}
=
\int_{S}\left(\nabla\times\vec{F}\right)_{z}\left({\rm d}\vec{S}\right)_{z}
=
\int_{S}\left(-2\right)\left({\rm d}\vec{S}\right)_{z}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large-2\pi}
$$

Comment: Does this use the correct normal? @lorde said the answer is $2\pi$.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is 2π.

Comment: @BennettGardiner
${\rm d}\vec{S}
 =
 \left\vert{\rm d}\vec{S}\right\vert\,\,\vec{\rm k}$